# How to query data with Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, sql

I am struggling on querying data as Example

```
----------
Date of Transaction  Customer_ID    Customer_Register_Status
20/09/2015            123              NEW
21/09/2015            123              Activate
22/09/2015            123              Activate
23/09/2015            123              Suspense
24/09/2015            123              Suspense
25/09/2015            123              Activate
26/09/2015            123              Activate
27/09/2015            123              Activate
28/09/2015            123              Activate
29/09/2015            123              Activate
30/09/2015            123              Activate
26/09/2015            123              Activate
27/09/2015            ABC              NEW
28/09/2015            ABC              NEW
29/09/2015            ABC              NEW
30/09/2015            ABC              NEW
01/09/2015            ABC              NEW
02/09/2015            ABC              NEW
```

My wishes result

```
Date of Transaction  Customer_ID    Customer_Register_Status
25/09/2015            123              Activate
27/09/2015            ABC              NEW
```

The Rules of is results

- Use Customer Register_status must display the latest status
- The Date must be the First date of changing last status
- In case of Customer_Register_Status is never Change the display must be displayed the First Date of transaction

Please guide me how to create a query to get the result

Comment: **Hint:** `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by `customer_register_status`, ordered by date descending.

Comment: Your example result is wrong

Comment: This is a very reasonable question, that is poorly described.  The OP seems to want the first date that the most recent status appeared.

Comment: @OP: I don't know how Gordon Linoff managed to decipher the question. But if he's right, then in your results, the 2nd row's `Customer_ID` value should be `ABC`, no?  Consider fixing your post to reduce the confusion (a little).

Comment: Sorry! I made the result wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first date of the last status . . . that is, the date of the switch to the last status.

Here is one method that does the following:

- Creates a flag when the status changes.
- Does a forward sum of the flag to create a `grp` to identify adjacent rows with the same status.
- Calculates the maximum date for each customer.
- Does an aggregation by customer and grp, keeping only the group where the maximum date matches the customer maximum date.

The SQL is:

```
select t.customer_id, min(dte), status
from (select dte, customer_id, status,
             sum(case when prev_status = status then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by customer_id) as statusgrp,
             max(dte) over (partition by customer_id) as maxdte
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(status) over (partition by customer_id order by dte) as prev_status
            from table t
           ) t
      ) t
group by customer_id, statusgrp, status, maxdte
having max(dte) = maxdte;
```